# Install Calibre Debian Sid

Tags: dependencies, debian, virtual, sid, calibre

I'm having problems installing calibre, when I use aptitude install calibre I get this output

```
root@debian:/home/gustavo# aptitude install calibre
The following NEW packages will be installed:
calibre calibre-bin{ab} javascript-common{a} libchm1{a}
libdouble-conversion1{a} libjs-jquery{a} libjs-sphinxdoc{a}
libjs-underscore{a} libpodofo0.9.0{a} libqt5clucene5{a}
libqt5designer5{a} libqt5help5{a} libqt5qml5{a} libqt5quick5{a}
libqt5svg5{a} libqt5webkit5{a} libtidy-0.99-0{a} libyaml-0-2{a}
python-apsw{a} python-beautifulsoup{a} python-bs4{a}
python-cherrypy3{a} python-cssselect{a} python-cssutils{a}
python-dateutil{a} python-dnspython{a} python-feedparser{a}
python-html5lib{a} python-lxml{a} python-markdown{a}
python-mechanize{a} python-netifaces{a} python-pygments{a}
python-pyparsing{a} python-pyqt5{ab} python-pyqt5.qtsvg{a}
python-pyqt5.qtwebkit{a} python-repoze.lru{a} python-routes{a}
python-sip{a} python-utidylib{a} python-webob{a} python-yaml{a}
0 packages upgraded, 43 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 157 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-pyqt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 which is a virtual package.
calibre-bin : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1) calibre [Not Installed]
2) calibre-bin [Not Installed]
3) python-pyqt5 [Not Installed]
4) python-pyqt5.qtsvg [Not Installed]
5) python-pyqt5.qtwebkit [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

What is the problem with the dependencies?
And I have already installed libqt5core5a witch is said to provide the virtual package for the qtbase-abi-5-3-2, please help me! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian *unstable* (aka *sid*) is mainly called *unstable* not because of the quality of the software but because of quirks with the dependencies.

in contrast, Debian *testing* (kind of) guarantees that only packages with resolvable dependencies are available.

So: if you want to have a *stable/working* system (and are no expert), you might want to avoid *unstable* (*testing* should be ok though).

And for what it is worth: as of *now*, the issue seems to be resolved

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the great answer!
The dependencies problem was resolved really fast so I think I will continue to use Sid. 

I am trying to become a more advanced user of Debian, and I think Sid with his 'problems' may be a good way to learn!

But I didn't know that the 'unstable' thing is because of the dependencies too, thanks for the information and the help! :)

Comment: actually i would recommend rather a *testing/unstable* mixture for everyday life.

Comment: and btw, if the answer answers your question you should *accept* it.

Comment: Hum, the mixture is a great idea, and sorry, i didn't know that I have to accept the answer..kkkk I'm new here, thanks! =]